# Error 1064 (42000) when adding tables with days punches in and out added

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a timeclock application for my company, and when I run this to add this to my table I get the following error.

Command:

```
 create table TimeClock 
( ID VARCHAR(20)
, Timestamp VARCHAR(20)
, Date VARCHAR(20)
, Name VARCHAR(20)
, MON-IN VARCHAR(20)
, MON-L-OUT VARCHAR(20)
, MON-L-IN VARCHAR(20)
, MON-OUT VARCHAR(20)
, TUE-IN VARCHAR(20)
, TUE-L-OUT VARCHAR(20)
, TUE-L-IN VARCHAR(20)
, TUE-OUT VARCHAR(20)
, WED-IN VARCHAR(20)
, WED-L-OUT VARCHAR(20)
, WED-L-IN VARCHAR(20)
, WED-OUT VARCHAR(20)
, THU-IN VARCHAR(20)
, THU-L-OUT VARCHAR(20)
, THU-L-IN VARCHAR(20)
, THU-OUT VARCHAR(20)
, FRI-IN VARCHAR(20)
, FRI-L-OUT VARCHAR(20)
, FRI-L-IN VARCHAR(20)
, FRI-OUT VARCHAR(20)
, SAT-IN VARCHAR(20)
, SAT-L-OUT VARCHAR(20)
, SAT-L-IN VARCHAR(20)
, SAT-OUT VARCHAR(20)
, SUN-IN VARCHAR(20)
, SUN-L-OUT VARCHAR(20)
, SUN-L-IN VARCHAR(20)
, SUN-OUT VARCHAR(20)
);
```

Ouput:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '-IN VARCHAR(20), MON-L-OUT VARCHAR(20), MON-L-IN
>   VARCHAR(20), MON-OUT VARCHAR(20' at line 1

Maybe I'm blind. But I can't find the syntax error. :(

I've run the command without the day in and outs. It worked. But I really need all of these values tracked in the punch system.

Comment: It's because of the `-` inside the column-names, it's being used as an operator. You can use them but then insert it like \`MON-IN\` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because of using `-` on column names without quoting. You can find the rules of the identifier names here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/identifier-names/

> Identifiers may be quoted using the backtick character `-`, `` ` ``, `.`. Quoting is optional for identifiers that don't contain special characters, or for identifiers that are not [reserved words](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reserved-words/).

**Now you have two possibilites:**

1. Quote the columns with backticks: `` `MON-IN` ``
2. Rename the columns and use `_` (underscore) instead of `-` (minus): `MON_IN`

Answer (score 0):

Your field names is causing you issues because of the `-` that is already a math operator (minus).

Imagine a table having 3 fields :

```
A | B | A-B
```

In a query, is `A-B` the field name or the operation `A - B` ?

To fix that, wrap backticks around field names, such as :

```
create table TimeClock (ID VARCHAR(20),
                        Timestamp VARCHAR(20),
                        Date VARCHAR(20),
                        Name VARCHAR(20),
                        `MON-IN` VARCHAR(20),
-- Notice this ---------^------^
                        ...
```

Or consider using a proper naming